# FTP Server with WEB Gui

Tags: ftp, owncloud

I've installed Owncloud in order to have both ftp managed and web managed file storage server.
The problem is owncloud doesn't support ftp connecting to server.
Do you know good alternatives?
Thank you!

Comment: Nobody uses FTP anymore. It is ancient, obsolete and difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following links:

A frontend built for VSFtpD (PHP5): https://github.com/Tvel/VsftpdWeb

With WebMIN: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-simplify-ftp-server-setup-with-webmin-and-vsftp/